# IPTABLES : How to limit per ip in selected network to access port 25 in a time unit

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a mail server, and i have a kinda bad habit users who like to click the send/receive button simultaneous in a second, causing the log flooded with unnecessary information.

I am trying to limit each ip address in my network (internal ip address) to be able to make a connection to mail server once in 30second, but it should not be applied to external ip addresses the mail server sometime will receive a forward mails from another allowed mail server.

I have read the manpage of iptables and found `--connlimit-above N` but that only limit the connection and not by time unit.

Anyone can show me how it can be done using the iptables or ufw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard case of rate-limiting:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 2 -j DROP
```

Here I assumed your LAN is *192.168.0.0/24* and your interface is *eth0*, if not, please change accordingly.

The first rule detects all *NEW* packets coming over *eth0* from your LAN,  and destined to TCP port 25, and adds the IP address to the *recent* list; the second command, upon receipt of a *NEW* packet on the same port, checks the *recent* list (*--update*) and, if the address was entered into the list less than *--seconds 30* ago , drops the packet if the given number of *--hitcounts 2* has been reached.

Please notice that this is applied only to **NEW** packets: if you have a legitimate conversation going on, you do not want to interphere with that, just block the establishing of another one. In this, my answer differs completely from Angelo's

Comment: is it possible to change this to fit ufw?

Comment: @JosephGoh Only partially: *ufw* can rate-limit a port only to **6 times per 30 seconds**. If this is what you want, read here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uncomplicated_Firewall#Rate_limiting_with_ufw

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have NOT tested this, so I apologize in advance if it doesn't work (but hopefully this will get you far enough to figure it out):

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN,ACK --dport 25 -m recent --name smtplimit --set
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --tcp-flags RST RST --dport 25 -m recent --name smtplimit --set
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m recent --name smtplimit --rcheck --seconds 30 --hitcount 1 -m limit --limit 1/minute -j LOG --log-prefix 'SMTP limit:'
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m recent --name smtplimit --rcheck --seconds 30 --hitcount 1 -j DROP
```